# Derivative of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^p+y^q}{x-y}$ if $x\neq y$ and $f(x,x) = 0$; $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The problem is to find $p,q$ such that

1. $\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y$ exist.
2. $\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y$ are continuous.
3. $f$ is differentiable

on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The only concern here is on $x=y$, where

$$
\partial f/\partial x = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^p+x^q}{h^2}.
$$

I think that the limit does not exists for any $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$ since binomial expansion of $(x+h)^p/h^2$ always gives at least one negative power of $h$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Notice that the existence of $\partial f/\partial x$ implies the continuity of the function $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$. Is this true in your case?

Comment: A more interesting exercise (check whether this was actually what the exercise asked) is to consider the function $f(x,y) = (x^p-y^q)/(x-y)$...

Comment: Not a very interesting problem. Is it really stated like this?

Comment: @zhw Yes, it is. It's one of many similar problems, only with different functions. This one just turned out not to even have a partial derivative.